# How to change search bar textarea to a drop-down menu in opencart?

Tags: php, search, drop-down-menu, opencart

I have some manufactures in my store and I want to modify the search so that you can choose the manufacture from a drop-down menu :)

I wish to change the search box into a drop-down menu in opencart. Is that possible? If yes, please tell me how.

Thank you !

Comment: These extensions for OpenCart are not necessarily what you're asking for but will do what you're asking for in a menu like style; thus allowing you to list links to manufacturers (or searches with the manufacturers name in the search). [Extension 1](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=7955) & [Extension 2](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=8322)

Comment: @Josh I can't use any extension because it is a project for my university and the professor has all the extensions, and he said we are not allowed to use extensions... so if I use one he will detect me... and I need to modify the search box, not the top menu :)

Comment: @Christina Ursu well I tried. Good luck :)

Comment: Nothing is impossible really. Where do you want the dropdown, on header search widget or the search page. Also, I do not see much use for it to be honest as you can just add the manufacturers module anywhere, whether as a list or a dropdown.

Comment: @B-and-P I use a sidebar search menu, and I need a drop-down menu instead of the textarea ... but I can also modify the top right search bar. I don't know if you understand me but I need to modify the search bar, so I can't write anything in it, but choose the manufacture, to search for, from a dropdown menu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I don't know why you are doing this, but here is one way...
I am using header search for this example, Opencart 1.5.4.1
Edit catalog/controller/commmon/header.php. After line 96:

```
$this->load->model('catalog/product');
```

add this:

```
        // - - Manufacturers Dropdown Data Start - - - - - - - - 
    // load manufacturer model
    $this->load->model('catalog/manufacturer');

    //get manufacturers data
    $manufacturers = $this->model_catalog_manufacturer->getManufacturers();

    //populate data array for use in view
    $this->data['manufacturers'] = array();
    foreach ($manufacturers as $manufacturer){
        $this->data['manufacturers'][] = array(
            'id'   => $manufacturer['manufacturer_id'],
            'name' => $manufacturer['name']
        );
    }

    // - - Manufacturers Dropdown Data End - - - - - - - - -
```

Now, in catalog/view/theme/xxx/template/common/header.tpl find search DIV, comment out the search input (lines 55-62):

```
<div id="search">

<!-- <div class="button-search"></div>
<?php if ($filter_name) { ?>
<input type="text" name="filter_name" value="<?php echo $filter_name; ?>" />
<?php } else { ?>
<input type="text" name="filter_name" value="<?php echo $text_search; ?>" onclick="this.value = '';" onkeydown="this.style.color = '#000000';" />
<?php } ?> -->
...
```

Add your select element:

```
<div id="search">

<!-- <div class="button-search"></div>
<?php if ($filter_name) { ?>
<input type="text" name="filter_name" value="<?php echo $filter_name; ?>" />
<?php } else { ?>
<input type="text" name="filter_name" value="<?php echo $text_search; ?>" onclick="this.value = '';" onkeydown="this.style.color = '#000000';" />
<?php } ?> -->


<select name='manuf_dropdown' ONCHANGE="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
<option value=''></option>
<?php foreach ($manufacturers as $manufacturer) { 
    if (isset($_GET['manufacturer_id']) && $_GET['manufacturer_id'] ==  $manufacturer['id']){
?>
    <option selected="selected" value="./?route=product/manufacturer/info&manufacturer_id=<?php echo $manufacturer['id'] ?>"><?php echo $manufacturer['name'] ?></option>
<?php } else { ?>

        <option value="./?route=product/manufacturer/info&manufacturer_id=<?php echo $manufacturer['id'] ?>"><?php echo $manufacturer['name'] ?></option>
<?php }} ?>
</select>
</div>
```

Let me know if you need any explanation of the code.